# asp Eval function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, eval

can i save the returning value of eval function in a variable and use it wherever i want?
i can call it just in `<asp: ....` tags. i can't use them in vb methods. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Eval("foo")` is a shortcut for `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "foo")`. Container.DataItem contains the actual data you're trying to get at, and the `Eval()` method simply uses reflection or other means to allow late binding on names.

If you want better compile-time type checking, you can always cast the `Container.DataItem` to whatever type you want.

You can also re-use `DataBinder.Eval()` elsewhere, as a shortcut for using Reflection.

Some examples of what you can do are below:

```
<%# DoSomethingWithData (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Foo")) %>

Sub DoSomethingWithData (Object data)
   SomeProperty = data
   DoSomethingWithData = data
End Sub

<%# DoSomethingWithDataStronglyTyped (Container.DataItem) %>

Sub DoSomethingWithDataStronglyTyped (Object data)
   Dim StronglyTyped as SomeType
   StronglyTyped = DirectCast (data, SomeType)
   DoSomethingWithDataStronglyTyped = DoSomethingElse(StronglyTyped)
End Sub

Sub ExampleOfDataBinderEvalReuse ()

   Dim StronglyTyped as SomeType
   StronglyTyped = GetSomeData()

   ' get "Foo" property of the SomeType class
   DataBinder.Eval(StronglyTyped, "Foo")
End Sub
```